# How to understand following single and double quotes terminology in C++?

Tags: c++

Help me understand the following:

```
cout<<'a'; //prints a and it's okay but
cout<<'ab'; //prints 24930 but I was expecting an error due to term 'ab' having two character in single quote
cout<<'a'+1; //prints 98 
cout<<"ab"; // prints ab and it's okay but
cout<<"ab"+1; // prints b, why?
cout<<"a"+1; // prints nothing ?
cout<<'a'+'b'; // prints 195 ?
cout<<"a"+"b"; // gives error ?
```

Please help me to understand all these things in details. I am very confused. I would be very thankful.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The `"ab"+1` and `"a"+1` cases are pointer arithmetic: you're advancing the pointer by one so that it starts at the second character, or in the second case starts at the end-of-string nul character. You can't concatenate strings like that in C++ in the last case, nor can you add a pointer to a pointer like you can add an int to one.

Comment: value of `'a'` in ascii is `97` (and `98` for `'b'`). That explains `'a' + 1` and `'a' + 'b'`.

Comment: 'ab' has no defined meaning in C++, but some compilers allow it. What it means depends on the compiler.

Comment: @Jarod42 And the operands are implicitly converted to `int` because of *integral promotion*.

Comment: I would recommend you to choose one of the books for beginners and start there. [C++ Books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @john -- `'ab'` is a [multicharacter literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal). Every conforming compiler allows it. Its value is implementation defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'a'` is a `char` type in C++. `std::cout` overloads `<<` for a `char` to output the character, rather than the character number.

`'ab'` is a *multicharacter literal* in C++. It must have an `int` type. Its value is *implementation defined*, but `'a' * 256 + 'b'` is common. With ASCII encoding, that is 24930. The overloaded `<<` operator for an `int` outputs the number.

`'a' + 1` is an arithmetic expression. `'a'` is converted to an `int` type prior to the addition according to the standard integral type promotion rules.

`"ab" + 1` is executing *pointer arithmetic* on the `const char[3]` type, so it's equivalent to `"b"`. Remember that `<<` has lower *precedence* than `+`.

`"a" + 1` is similar to the above but only the NUL-terminator is output.

`'a' + 'b'` is an `int` type. Both arguments are converted to an `int` prior to the addition.

The arguments of `"a" + "b"` *decay* to `const char*` types prior to the addition. But that's the addition of two pointers, which is not valid C++.